# git merge branch and uncommitted changes to master

Tags: git

I have kind of a tricky situation here.

Two employees have been working on a project using git.
Both cloned the original master.

- Employee 1 created a branch to develop a small feature.
- Employee 2 made major changes without committing them or creating a branch.

Somehow, the work of both employees now needs to be merged back into the master.
I know in advance that there will be a few conflicts in CSS files, and these will most likely need to be resolved manually.

What is the best way to proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employee 2 needs to commit or stash his changes before he can merge changes from others. They can follow these steps to merge:

Employee 1 merges his changes back to `master`, to avoid unnecessary merge commit, he may first `rebase` his feature branch on `master`:

1. git checkout `employee_1_feature_branch`; # not needed if already in this branch
2. git rebase master
3. git checkout master
4. git merge `employee_1_feature_branch`
5. git push origin master

Employee 2 commits his changes, and merge changes from Employee 1:

1. git add .
2. git commit -m 'changes from employee 2'
3. git pull --rebase origin master; # may need to manually resolve conflicts after this
4. git push origin master

Or if Employee 2 does not want to make a commit before merging(i.e. merge first and then commit), he can do the following:

1. git add .
2. git stash
3. git pull --rebase origin master
4. git stash pop; # may need to manually resolve conflicts after this
5. ...edit what is needed to be edited...
6. git add .
7. git commit -m 'changes from Employee 2'
8. git push origin master

That's it.

Comment: Looks great, but is it necessary for Employee 1 to rebase?  I ask because he may have already pushed his changes.

Comment: If he has already pushed, meaning his commits were the latest changes in the repo, and there were no conflicts or he resolved the conflicts, so it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

First integrate the small feature.

Then ask your second employee to

- create a branch,
- add and commit his/her evolution in that branch
- fetch from the upstream repo
- rebase that branch on top origin/master:

  ```
  git rebase origin/master
  ```

That will replay those commits on top of the updated `master` (which now included the small feature).
The work for solving any conflict will be on Employee 2.
Once that is done, a simply `git push` will be enough to push the updated branch, and a trivial merge can be done to integrate it to `master`.